# How do I successfully select a newly created element with Mustache using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm generating some HTML based on a mustache template, as such:

```
function generate_hello(element) {
    var template = jQuery('#hello_template');
    return mustache(template.html(), {
        tooltip: 'Hello'
    });
    ..nothing gets executed here, no selecting in jQuery, no nothing.
}
```

And so, the element:

```
<input type='button' value='Hello' class='show'>
```

Is born! Awesome.

Except this doesn't work if I am to put it after the `return mustache...`

```
jQuery('.show');
```

Nor does this:

```
$('.show');
```

And rightfully so. A `return` means stop execution.
Now, I've added that selector before and after the return, removed the return (can't remove the return, because then it just doesn't output the HTML) but nothing works.

How can I select my newly created element to play with it?

Comment: how do you know `$('.show')` does not work ? have you tried checking `$('.show').lenght;` etc ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Yup! Did my due dilligence, but I'll go at it again. Edit: Nope, doesn't work. Anything after the `return` doesn't get executed (as it should be, but I'm wondering, should I just de-couple that mustache routine into another function?

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve after selecting it ? adding any event etc ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Correct! This basically adds a button that I'll then manipulate its value, do some AJAX stuff, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that your newly created element is actually in the DOM?

Comment: When this element is created using mustache, is it added to the page immediately? Selectors like `.show` will search the active DOM for the element, so if the element is created but not yet added to the page, it won't be found.

Comment: @TylerRoper and Dave: Yup, can confirm, the element is there even before Mustache renders it and the other items as well.

Comment: Maybe I'm beating a dead horse but generate_hello() looks a lot like it's returning a string that never goes anywhere. Can you show the code that calls that function?

Comment: @DaveGoldberg Fixed the issue, writing an answer. I'm often dumbed by issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that you're trying to attach event on dynamically added elements and that just takes a little bit more than adding events in normal routines.

This is how you do it

```
$('body').on('click', '.show', function() {
  alert("Clicked on element with class show")
});
```

**Update:**

```
function generate_hello(element) {
    var template = jQuery('#hello_template');
    return mustache(template.html(), {
        tooltip: 'Hello'
    });
    ..nothing gets executed here, no selecting in jQuery, no nothing.
}
```

*nothing gets executed here, no selecting in jQuery, no nothing*

This is because you are returning from the function. And nothing is executed after return statement. Write your code in some other function and call it after `generate_hello` function.

Something like

```
generate_hello();
someOtherFunction
```

Comment: That's a good note, but unfortunately, my issue really is the fact that nothing executes after my mustache's return.

Comment: Yup, you were about 90% right, with a little less spice. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the comments as well as the other answer for **valuable information.**

The issue is not really with the code, but rather how I designed my *system*, errr, logic.

This code is being called in a wrapper function (one level above) as such:

```
var markup = $(window[callback](e.currentTarget));
markup.attr('data-screen', callback);
wrapper.append(markup);
```

Naturally, I'm simply appending (to my `wrapper`) a string of html (`markup`), this obviously doesn't allow for anything to be done inside my original functions, **because it simply outputs and nothing more.**

It takes the data from my HTML:

```
<div class="test" data-callback="generate_markup">
```

And just executed that callback, which is my original `generate_hello`. Nothing more.

The solution here is to, after it's done with outputting, execute another callback, so, after my `wrapper.append(markup);` I'd just call my second callback:

```
var markup = $(window[callback](e.currentTarget));
markup.attr('data-screen', callback);
wrapper.append(markup);
secondary_callback_after_markup_is_done();
```

I guess the lesson here is: Control your logic and know what each function returns and how it's handled.